# function parameter eror, exit code 1 : invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax, parameters

i make a function for my program for fuzzyfication on fuzzy logic task. and i have some problem when i declare a function like this.

```
"""Emosi"""
def emosi(x):
 if(x<=25):
    miuemosi = ([1,"sabar"],[0,"labil"])
 elif (x>25 and x<50):
    miuemosi = ([kurvaturun(x,25,50),"sabar"],[kurvanaik(x,25,50),"labil"])
 elif (x=50):
    miuemosi =([1,"labil"],[0,"emosian"])
 elif (x>50 and x<75):
    miuemosi = ([kurvaturun(x,50,75),"labil"],[kurvanaik(x,50,75),"emosian"])
 elif (x>=75):
    miuemosi = ([1,"emosian"],[0,"sabar"])
 return  miuemosi
```

and i have error like this

```
 File "F:/.PERKULIAHAN NUMERO UNO/SM5/ImInLoveWithSekre/ILoveAIsoMuch(kiss).py", line 11
   def emosi:
            ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error message does not correspond to the posted code.

Comment: Please correct your question. I'm getting the next error with your code: elif (x=50):
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have following error with the code in question:

> ```
>   File "D:/Develop/Python/TestCAE/test2.py", line 7
>     elif (x=50):
>            ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

The error was caused by wrong comparison in if statement with a usage "=" instead of "=="

I fixed code like this:

```
"""Emosi"""
def emosi(x):
 if(x<=25):
    miuemosi = ([1,"sabar"],[0,"labil"])
 elif (x>25 and x<50):
    miuemosi = ([kurvaturun(x,25,50),"sabar"],[kurvanaik(x,25,50),"labil"])
 elif (x==50):
    miuemosi =([1,"labil"],[0,"emosian"])
 elif (x>50 and x<75):
    miuemosi = ([kurvaturun(x,50,75),"labil"],[kurvanaik(x,50,75),"emosian"])
 elif (x>=75):
    miuemosi = ([1,"emosian"],[0,"sabar"])
 return  miuemosi
```

And now it works without any errors

Answer (score 0):

The code that you ran has the line `def emosi:` in it, which does not match the code you shared here. Function definitions must contain parentheses and arguments.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17748334)

Comment: It addresses the error that the poster is asking about, so it seems fair to me. Thanks for the suggestion though, I’ll post a comment next time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others: The code first provided and the error message does not match.

However, running the code first provided should work if you have defined "kurvaturun" and "kurvanaik". Also, at `elif (x=50):` you have to add another equal sign for python to understand that you are comparing and not assigning values, like this: `elif (x==50):`

When I say it "works" I mean that `emosi(50)`, for example, returns `([1, 'labil'], [0, 'emosian'])`

The SyntaxError can come from that you forgot to add parentheses after your function name. All functions, methods and classes have to have parentheses even if they have no arguments.